# Select an HTML element and remove part of it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im using jquery to select an HTML element, and after that i need to remove part of it. Is it possible? if so how can i do it? This is what i get when i `console.log()` the element i selected and i need to remove the elements that are highlighted. I tried using `delete element.1` but its wrong

[image]

EDIT:

Im adding more info. Im trying to clone the first `TR` in a `TBody`. This is what i have before clone.
[image]
This is what i have after clone:
[image]
as you can see the clone creates those elementes and put them after the cloned element. I need to remove them. Thats whyi tried the `delete element.1`

```
var e = $('.duplicateTR :first-child').clone().appendTo(e);
```

```js
var element = $('duplicateTR :first-child');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table style="width: 100%!important;" class="documents_table common_table table table-striped" id="documento_detalhe">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Ano Doc</th>
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Codigo Doc</th>
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Numero Doc</th>
        <th class="text_center">Numero Linha</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo Produto</th>
        <th class="text_center">Descricao produto</th>
        <th class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
        <th class="text_center">Preco</th>
        <th class="text_center">Lote</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo armazem</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo CC</th>
        <th class="text_center">centro Custo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text_center duplicateTR " id="tbody">
      <tr style="text-align: center;" class=" doc_line">
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="ANO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">2021</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">FEN</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">111</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_LINHA" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">30</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_PRODUTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">X4321</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">Edif.Out.Const.c/IVA Dedutível (ATIVO FIXO TANGIVEL)</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="QUANTIDADE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="PRECO_UNITARIO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="LOTE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">423</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_ARMAZEM" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">1</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_CENTRO_CUSTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">02.0012.N323</td>
        <td data-type="C" data-field="CENTRO_CUSTO_DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">323 Coimbra 2</td>
        <td class="text_center edit_line" onclick="edit_line(this)" style="color:#04a9f5;cursor:pointer"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center fontDisabled save_line"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center delete_line" onclick="remove_line(this)" data-line_number="30 " data-docyea="2021" data-doccod="FEN" data-docnbr="111" style="color:red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: center;" class=" doc_line">
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="ANO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">2021</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">FEN</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">111</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_LINHA" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">30</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_PRODUTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">X4321</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">Edif.Out.Const.c/IVA Dedutível (ATIVO FIXO TANGIVEL)</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="QUANTIDADE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="PRECO_UNITARIO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="LOTE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">423</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_ARMAZEM" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">1</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_CENTRO_CUSTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">02.0012.N323</td>
        <td data-type="C" data-field="CENTRO_CUSTO_DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">323 Coimbra 2</td>
        <td class="text_center edit_line" onclick="edit_line(this)" style="color:#04a9f5;cursor:pointer"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center fontDisabled save_line"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center delete_line" onclick="remove_line(this)" data-line_number="30 " data-docyea="2021" data-doccod="FEN" data-docnbr="111" style="color:red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="text-align: center;" class=" doc_line">
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="ANO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">2021</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">FEN</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">111</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_LINHA" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">30</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_PRODUTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">X4321</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">Edif.Out.Const.c/IVA Dedutível (ATIVO FIXO TANGIVEL)</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="QUANTIDADE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="PRECO_UNITARIO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="LOTE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">423</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_ARMAZEM" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">1</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_CENTRO_CUSTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">02.0012.N323</td>
        <td data-type="C" data-field="CENTRO_CUSTO_DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">323 Coimbra 2</td>
        <td class="text_center edit_line" onclick="edit_line(this)" style="color:#04a9f5;cursor:pointer"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center fontDisabled save_line"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center delete_line" onclick="remove_line(this)" data-line_number="30 " data-docyea="2021" data-doccod="FEN" data-docnbr="111" style="color:red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want just select `element.0` ?

Comment: yes i just need the element.0. The problem is that in my code i doing a `clone()` and the clone is adding those 1, 2, 3, 4 to my main element and i dont know why, thats why i need to remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got it working by selecting the first-child element after the clone.

```
var e = $('.duplicateTR :first-child').clone();
$(e).first().appendTo(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want first child on the element, you can do it with jQuery like this:

```
var element = $('.duplicateTR').first();
```

If you want remove all except first element, i prefer this trick:

```
var keepingElement = $('.duplicateTR').first();
var parent = $('.duplicateTR');
parent.empty();
parent.append(keepingElement);
```

Comment: that wont work. did you even try it before posting? It removes all TR's

Comment: @BRABO maybe I didn't understand your problem completely! Sorry. Let's solve it. In second image you want to remove elements inside red box, Am I right?

Comment: Yes i need to remove them using their index

Comment: Ok. your HTML code that posted in question has many problems. can you add your codes in https://jsfiddle.net/ @BRABO

Comment: what problems does it have? it works fine. After messing around i got the js working. thanks anyway

Comment: i did like this to work `var e = $('.duplicateTR :first-child').clone(); $(e).first().appendTo(id);`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fa-edit, .fa-check, .fa-times").forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

Or, with jQuery, you can do this instead :

```js
$( ".fa-edit, .fa-check, .fa-times" ).remove();
```

Comment: that removes all, not what i need, i have multiple lines

Comment: @BRABO Check your console. Both versions should remove each of the three elements you want to remove!

Comment: the problem is that i have multiple lines and that code removes those elements from all lines

Comment: @BRABO : Then you need to be more specific. I'll need more info on the rest of your code to tell you exactly what to do, but really all you need to do is use my code with the right CSS selectors. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors to learn how to select precisely the elements you want to remove... and only those elements...

Comment: i need to remove them using the index if possible not by class or id

Comment: @BRABO : Please update your code so the behavior in your demo corresponds with what we see in the screenshot. That makes it a lot easier for everyone to understand what is happening and why...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a clone then after clone you need to assign uniq id to cloned HTML and get HTML specific HTML element using ID

```
$(".parent-class-" + id + " .child-class")
```

it select only specific child element of that parent class

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove the fist element with `$element.children()[1].remove();`
2. The elements with specific classes can be removed with `$element.find('.fas.fa-edit, .fas.fa-check, .fas.fa-times').remove();`

```js
const $element = $('.duplicateTR :first-child');

// remove the first element
$element.children()[1].remove();

// remove elements with specific classes
$element.find('.fas.fa-edit, .fas.fa-check, .fas.fa-times').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table style="width: 100%!important;" class="documents_table common_table table table-striped" id="documento_detalhe">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Ano Doc</th>
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Codigo Doc</th>
        <th style="display:none;" class="text_center">Numero Doc</th>
        <th class="text_center">Numero Linha</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo Produto</th>
        <th class="text_center">Descricao produto</th>
        <th class="text_center">Quantidade</th>
        <th class="text_center">Preco</th>
        <th class="text_center">Lote</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo armazem</th>
        <th class="text_center">Codigo CC</th>
        <th class="text_center">centro Custo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text_center duplicateTR " id="tbody">
      <tr style="text-align: center;" class=" doc_line">
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="ANO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">2021</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">FEN</td>
        <td style="display:none" data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_DOCUMENTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">111</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="NUMERO_LINHA" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">30</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_PRODUTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">X4321</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">Edif.Out.Const.c/IVA Dedutível (ATIVO FIXO TANGIVEL)</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="QUANTIDADE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="PRECO_UNITARIO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">12</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="LOTE" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">423</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_ARMAZEM" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">1</td>
        <td data-type="D" data-field="CODIGO_CENTRO_CUSTO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">02.0012.N323</td>
        <td data-type="C" data-field="CENTRO_CUSTO_DESCRICAO" class=" class=" text_center "=" " documento_numero_linha"="">323 Coimbra 2</td>
        <td class="text_center edit_line" onclick="edit_line(this)" style="color:#04a9f5;cursor:pointer"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center fontDisabled save_line"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
        <td class="text_center delete_line" onclick="remove_line(this)" data-line_number="30 " data-docyea="2021" data-doccod="FEN" data-docnbr="111" style="color:red"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: thanks but i need to remove them by index not by class or id

Comment: @BRABO, you can check the example above `$element.children()[1].remove();` removes by index where `[1]` is the index.